# Proof about binary structures and binary operations

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, binary-operations

> Suppose that $*$ is an associative and commutative binary operation on a set S. Show that the subset $$T=\{a  \in S \mid a*a=a \}$$ of $S$ is closed under $*$.

**Proof:** We need to show that if $a\in T$ and $b \in T $, then $a*b\in T$ Let $a\in T$ and $b \in T$, so $a \in S$ and $b \in S$ which implies $a*b \in S$. $a*b=(a*a)*(b*b)$ and since $*$ is associative , we can get rid of the parenthesis, so $(a*a)*(b*b)=a*a*b*b$. * is also commutative, so $a*a*b*b=a*b*a*b$. We can also ad back parenthesis to make it more clear, $a*b*a*b=(a*b)*(a*b)$, so $a*b\in T$ which implies $T$ of $S$ is closed under $*$

How does that look?

Comment: Not as clear as it coulld be. Start by saying that we need to show that if $a$ and $b$ are in $T$, then $a\ast b$ is in $T$. Then compute $(a\ast b)\ast(a\ast b)$,  doing the computation in some detail, and making the uses of associativity and commutativity explicit.

Comment: How does that look now?

Comment: Much better. The "get rid of parentheses" is informal, and at an early stage in an abstract algebra course would be considered too much so. I would prefer going in the $(a\ast b)\ast(a\ast b)=\dots=(a\ast a)\ast(b\ast b)=a\ast b$ direction, since it makes the logic clearer.  But of course if we have proved $x=y$ we have proved $y=x$.

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence of your proof begins with a symbol which is sometimes frowned upon. You can insert some words such as 'Note that' or 'We have' to avoid this.

Instead of 'hence', you should 'since' (you are using the properties of $\ast$ you were given, you are not concluding something about $\ast$).

I think you should show some more steps to justify the equation $a\ast b = (a\ast b)\ast(a\ast b)$. Something along the lines of

\begin{align*}
a\ast b &= (a\ast a)\ast (b\ast b)\\
&= a \ast (a \ast b) \ast b\\
&= a \ast (b\ast a) \ast b\\
&= (a\ast b)\ast(a\ast b).
\end{align*}

Instead of saying 'which implies $T$ of $S$ is closed under $\ast$', I think you should say something of the lines of 'which shows $T$ is closed under $\ast$'.

Despite my comments on how your proof is written, your *approach* to the proof is correct.

Comment: Instead of handling the parenthesis, I just said we can get rid of them. I think that's also valid right?

Comment: Sure. The benefit of the way I have written it is that it emphasizes where commutativity is used.